# NHibernate: getting multiple entities with subset of child collection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate, detachedcriteria

My classes look something like this (I include only the relevant properties):

```
public class Order 
{
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
   public virtual IEnumerable<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine 
{
   public virtual string Product { get; set; } // Simplified
}
```

Now I What I want is to create a detached criteria that selects all orders for a given customer, and at the same time retrieves only the first 10 OrderLines for each order. The first part is easy:

```
Customer someCustomerObject = ...;
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Order>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Customer", someCustomerObject);
```

But how do I instruct NHibernate to retrieve eagerly the first 10 orderlines for each order retrieved by the criteria above?

I've tried using a Filter based on the following example (taken from Nhibernate documentation):

```
session.CreateFilter( lazyCollection, "").SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(10).List();
```

But when I give `Order.OrderLines` to the `CreateFilter` method, it retrieves all orderlines first, and then afterwards retrieves the 10 first orderlines, which is not what I want. I also tried combining this with a call to `NHibernateUtil.Initialize` to no avail.

How do I create a detached criteria for this problem? Or, if that is not entirely possible, how to I retrieve, for each order, the 10 first results only, without fetching the entire collection?

Comment: What happens if you make the call to SetMaxResults on "criteria" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `batch-size` property to 10 in the NHibernate mapping file for the Order class. This way it eagerly loads the first 10 elements of the collection and lazy-loads the rest of elements. I would map the collection as follows:

```
<set name="OrderLines" table="OrderToOrderLine" batch-size="10">
    <key column="OrderId"/>
    <one-to-many class="OrderLine"/>
</set>
```

More information, read on: [NHibernate Mapping - Collections](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/13/nhibernate-mapping-lt-set-gt.aspx)